# Cypress Click on Button table/grid

Tags: html, cypress

I have a table, using DIVs that contain customer data. I need click on button delete only of one button `nat=Delete` but row is same name elements. Below is an example of my table:

```
<div class=`customer-table`>
    <div class=`row activemember`>
         <div class=`col-1`><a href=`#`>Holiday,John</a></div>
         <div class=`col-1`>8675309</div>
    </div>
    <div class=`row activemember`>
         <div class=`col-1`><a href=`#`>Doe,Jen</a></div>
         <div class=`col-1`>123524</div>
         <div class=`col-1`><button nat=`buttonDelete` type=`button` class=`btn btn-danger btn-xs` title=`Delete` tabindex=`-1`> <i class=`fa fa-remove`></i> </button></div>
    </div>
    <div class=`row activemember`>
         <div class=`col-1`><a href=`#`>Holiday,John</a></div>
         <div class=`col-1`>8675309</div>
         <div class=`col-1`><button nat=`buttonDelete` type=`button` class=`btn btn-danger btn-xs` title=`Delete` tabindex=`-1`> <i class=`fa fa-remove`></i> </button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for some reason the prev() doesn't work

Comment: What is the exact issue you are running into? What error does using `prev()` throw? What do you need to validate before/after clicking the button?

Comment: Precisely click on the button of the line that has the desired value in the case "Holidays, John",

Comment: i start but not click

cy.get('@grid')
                    .within(($list) => {
                        cy.screenshot('linhaGrid')
                        const $el = cy.find("Holiday, John")
                        if ($el.length > 0) {
                            cy.wrap($el).first().click();
                        }
                    })

Comment: There's a number of things wrong with your provided code. I'll write up an answer to your question in one moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using this provided code:

```js
cy.get('@grid') 
  .within(($list) => { 
    cy.screenshot('linhaGrid') 
    const $el = cy.find("Holiday, John") 
    if ($el.length > 0) { 
        cy.wrap($el).first().click(); 
    } 
  })
```

```js
// Translation of original
cy.get('@grid')
  .screenshot('linhaGrid')
  .contains('Holiday, John')
  .parents('.row')
  .find('button')
  .click();
```

1. `.find()` should not be chained off of cy directly. [See documentation][1]
2. `.find()` takes a selector, and not a text value. To find an element based on text value, use `.contains()`
3. You should not assign variables based on return values of `cy.` commands. This will most likely not behave as you'd like.
4. `.contains()` only yields the first element found (even if there are multiple matches)
   [1]: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#Syntax

But, all of that being said -- the code still won't work. Why? Your first row does not contain a button. To add a little safeguarding to make sure you only select the first button with the provided text...

```js
it('Tests something', () => {
...
  let clicked = false;
  cy.get('@grid')
    .screenshot('linhaGrid')
    .find('button')
    .each(($button) => {
      if (!clicked && $button.parents('.row').contains('Holiday, John').length) {
        cy.wrap($button).click();
        clicked = true
      }
    })
})
```

This should work because you are finding *all* instances of the button, and then checking if their parent elements (.row) have a child element that contains the specified text. Additionally, but checking for `clicked`, it will only click on the first one that is found, as after clicking we set `clicked` to true.